# Cause for ICMP traffic from Cisco VPN clients towards Apple subnets after blocking HTTP traffic to Apple domains

Tags: network, vpn

In my environment, I have a few Macs that are connected via Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

I noticed that a few of these Macs occasionally send several ICMP request packets (up to 100+, each packet is approx. 1386 bytes and 4158 bytes) towards different Apple owned IP addresses (e.g: 17.253.83.201 - 17.253.83.206).

The only commonality I have is that whenever these devices send ICMP request packets over to Apple IPs, they often have prior HTTP denied traffic towards Apple domains.

Is this behaviour expected? Can’t seems to find any indicator from Apple documentation or forum that may explain this behaviour.

The logical explanation I can think of is ICMP is just another alternative way for a Mac to “double check” if they can establish a connection to the Apple server for any potential updates or task but there is no actual confirmation from the Apple dev team on my guess.

Many thanks in advance!